# Symfony2 & Doctrine - column is not inserted

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm stuck with with strange error

```
$thread->setTypeId($request->get('typeId'));
$thread->setStatusId(ThreadStatus::DRAFT);
$thread->setDateCreated(new \DateTime('now'));

var_dump($thread);
$this->em->persist($thread);
$this->em->flush();
```

I'm inserting value to non-nullable column 'typeId'. It is set in $request->get('typeId'), var_dump shows it is set in my entity, but inserting generates sql error

```
INSERT INTO threads (typeId, statusId, authorId, dateCreated, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ...)' with params [null, 1, 1, "2014-10-19 16:26:22", ...]
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'typeId' cannot be null
```

value for typeId is set as null. But why? What am I missing?

Comment: Is typeId set as auto_increment?

Comment: @HermannStephaneNtsamo no

    `/*
    * @ORM\Column(name="typeId", type="integer")
    */
    private $typeId;`

Comment: run >>> `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`
To make sure that you DB is in sync with your anotations.

Comment: @HermannStephaneNtsamo didn't help, same thing

Comment: If you go to your DB and `DESCRIBE threads;` Does it show typeId as a PK?

Comment: @HermannStephaneNtsamo no, it's foreign key, but relation seems to be ok

Comment: Ok, can you share the code in the Thread entity for the method `setTypeId`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63309/discussion-between-hermann-stephane-ntsamo-and-vebbo).

Comment: @HermannStephaneNtsamo  it generated by doctrine and it's working fine as i mentioned in main post
`public function setTypeId($typeId) {
        $this->typeId = $typeId;

        return $this;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You must to add `nullable=true`.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="typeId", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */

private $typeId;
```

Then run: php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: this column shouldn't be nullable, but I managaed to resolve the problem. Instead of setting `typeId` I set `type` as object from referenced table. It works fine now

Comment: Right, You should do like that :).